# Looking for a task application in GNOME without evolution prerequisite

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gtd, to-do

Currently I'm using Tomboy to write notes, including a TODO list. I'm looking a real task application to hold my TODO list.

In gnome, there are `tasque` and `tasks`, but both need `evolution-data-server`. Is there any other task application that not have evolution prerequisite?

I'm using Ubuntu Karmic Koala 9.10

TIA

Comment: Interested in GTD? Join [Personal Productivity and Organization](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity-and-organization-gtd-covey-etc), we are looking for users & experts... :)

Answer (score 1):

These aren't desktop-based, so might not fit your needs; but I find them useful.

I use the tasks portion of Mozilla's Sunbird & Lightning.
Also, http://www.rememberthemilk.com/ is good; as is Google's tasks.

Comment: I tried adding links to the software/services suggested, but I don't seem to have enough reputation to add more than one link.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. While you can't put a link, you can put the url in your answers. I'm already using remember the milk, and I also use google calendar and integrate it to Mozilla Thunderbird. I just want to find out a simple application to used while offline, since my internet connection is not too reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently installing `gtodo-applet` package. I'll try this one, while waiting other suggestion.